# Indicate to user that there's more items in the list

Tags: flutter

I have a list of items between 5 and 10. Sometimes it's not intuitive if there's more items in the list(usually 5 appear on screen) and I'm looking to add a down arrow(vertical list view) by the last visible item in the list to inform the user there's more items in the list..I had a quick search around but haven't come across anything like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a little hard to do, but if you can make it so that your list shows 5 *and a fraction* of the next item, it's super intuitive that the list continues, just by seeing only part of the next item.

I don't know if there is any package in flutter that automatically does anything like it though.